# Constant Xbox Entries in My Bridged Modem System Logs

Tags: networking, router, modem

I have a CenturyLink C3000Z modem bridged to an Orbi router. In the modem, I set the IPv4 firewall as medium and unchecked all the Xbox settings as well as anything gaming as we don't have or use an Xbox. The system log in the CL configuration fills up with entries like the following, multiple times a minute. MAC address is the MAC address for the modem as well as the SRC IP.

```
02/05/2024 04:08:11 AM Firewall 
Firewall DROP XBox:IN=br0 OUT=ppp0.1
MAC= 
SRC=192.168.0.3 DST=1.0.0.1 LEN=64 TOS=0x00
PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP
SPT=53009 DPT=53 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN
URGP=0
```

Sometimes the DST is: DST=205.171.3.25
WINDOW is sometimes shown as 29200
ID and SPT change with each entry.

Can anyone explain why are these appearing?

Answer (score 1):

Not an explanation of how this is happening, but changes to prevent XBox activity. Though it might be possible to uninstall Xbox, a future Windows update might reinstall it. Therefore it is more reliable to *disable* its Windows Services. Perform the following as Administrator:

[image: Disable Xbox]

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type *services*, and select *Services* or *services.msc*.
- Scroll to the *Xbox* services, shown below.
- Double-click each and *Stop* the service if it is *Running*.
- Set *Startup type* to *Disabled*.
- If you get an error that a services *Startup type* cannot be changed, it can be [disabled using Regedit](https://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-services-regedit.html), as shown below. However, to do so, you'd need to [take ownership of that Registry key](https://www.maketecheasier.com/full-ownership-windows-registry-keys/). There is *some* risk in editing the Windows Registry, so if stopping and disabling the other Xbox (dis)services stops the continual logging, this might be left undone.

[image: Disable Service via Registry]

Comment: I have already done this to all computers.

Comment: @MerciMe - [Edit] your question to reflect that very important vital necessary information

Comment: @Ramhound  Not sure what edit you are recommending.  What is not clear?

Comment: Well. Your question makes no mention of doing what is described in this answer

Answer (score 0):

I FIGURED IT OUT!  Disabling Xbox in the system services was not enough.  Under the 'Xbox Live Game Save' is a 'Recovery' tab and the 3 fields that tell the system what to do if the service fails was set to "Restart The Service".  Once I changed it to "Take No Action", it stopped posting to the system log!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).